# Calculate distances and keeping ID R

Tags: r

I found for each coordinates in data 1 its nearest coordinates in data 2 and then I calculated the distance between with the following code :

```r
library(gdistance)
library(geosphere)
d <- pointDistance(data1[,1:2],data2[,4:3], lonlat=TRUE, allpairs=T)
i <- apply(d, 1, which.min)
data2$distance_mpro = d[cbind(1:nrow(d), i)]
```

Here is data 1 :

```r
   Longitude    Latitude      id
1     15.7822  -1.7176809   PRO_1
2     17.4817  -2.8173532   PRO_2
3     16.9985  -2.5507654   PRO_3
...
186   24.7671  -3.1049599 PRO_186
```

And here is data 2 :

```r
    centre_code  latitude_exetat longitude_exetat 
1         11002      -4.3518           15.328     
2         11001      -4.3461           15.339      
3         11003      -4.3528           15.324    
4         11004      -4.3587           15.322     
...
```

The output is the following :

```r
   centre_code  latitude_exetat longitude_exetat distance_mpro
1         11002      -4.3518           15.328        69.287
2         11001      -4.3461           15.339        70.547
3         11003      -4.3528           15.324        68.940
4         11004      -4.3587           15.322        68.315
...
```

However how could I keep the id from my data1 and then obtain the following output ?

```r
    centre_code  latitude_exetat longitude_exetat distance_mpro  id 
1         11002      -4.3518           15.328        69.287      PRO_5
2         11001      -4.3461           15.339        70.547      PRO_2
3         11003      -4.3528           15.324        68.940      PRO_4
4         11004      -4.3587           15.322        68.315.     PRO_2
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You had better to provide two example data of  data 1 and 2 (several rows is enough) in code form.

Comment: Do you want to add `id` column to `data2`? `data2$id = data1$id`

Comment: I would like to know which object ( or ID) of data1 is actually the closest from data 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
d <- pointDistance(data2[,4:3],data1[,1:2], lonlat=TRUE, allpairs=T)
i <- apply(d, 1, which.min)

data2$distance_mpro = apply(d, 1, min)

data2$id = data1[i,]$id
```